# How callbacks are registered to a particular phases in nodejs

Tags: node.js

following the doc on [eventloop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/),

consider following snippet,

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');

fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Hello World!');
  console.log("Response sent");
  res.end();
}).listen(8081);

setInterval(() => console.log("Timeout callback"), 1000)
```

Now, since nodejs is event-driven, I am assuming under the hood nodejs will trigger a node-specific event.

**Question 1: Am I correct in my assumption?**

Now, when there is a incoming HTTP request to nodejs, and the function code and related variables resides outside of eventloop. This means there should be data structure to bridge this gap.

**Question 2**: How a event encountered in nodejs executes a callback function in a particular phase?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The event loop is orthogonal to variables. And I'm not sure what "phases" you talk about - when the event loop executes everything will be executed at the same phase - the execution. It just picks up pending executions and runs them but that doesn't have at different stages within the same iteration of the loop but the same phase of different iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, my approach to understand how even-loop works is different from you but I show my understanding based on your code (I added some more synchronous line of code for ease of explanation)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');

// Every time Nodejs faces a block of synchronous code, it will push this function into a call-stack (the execution stack like other programming language)
console.log('run 1');

// Everty time NodeJS faces a block of asynchronous code, it will pass its jobs and its callback function to a lib called libuv to handle.
// when libuv finishs its job (asynchronous operation), it will push the callback function into a queue called event-queue
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});

// Another synchronous code
console.log('run 2');

// Another asynchronous code
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Hello World!');
  console.log("Response sent");
  res.end();
}).listen(8081);
```

After all of the comments, you can imagine that we have a stack and a queue.
Event-loop's repetitive job is

**STEP 1**: Looking into the stack (call-stack), if any function inside, execute it till the stack is empty.

**STEP 2**: Look into the queue (event-queue), if any function inside, execute it till the queue is empty.

**STEP 3**: Repeat STEP 1.

P/S: For more detail and visualization, this video is the best source which describes how event-loop works. Hope this help

[LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)